# Ensure node is running at least a certain kernel version?

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, puppet, docker

I'm trying to create a development environment using Vagrant which depends on certain applications running inside of Docker containers.

The required environment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which maps out to be the `precise64` box in Vagrant. The problem is ensuring the following:

1. The Saucy LTS kernel is installed.
2. The Saucy LTS kernel is *running*.

I'm trying to provision the box using Puppet and I can't figure out a way to ensure that the following commands are executed:

```
apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-saucy linux-headers-generic-lts-saucy
reboot
```

I'll obviously need to reboot the box for it to load and run the new kernel.

Is there a way I can define these items as dependencies in Puppet?

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
package { "lxc-docker":
    /* ... */
    requires => Package["lts-kernel-saucy"]
}
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best and easiest solution here is to [use a Vagrant box which supports Docker by running the right kernel](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/11/08/docker-friendly-vagrant-boxes/).

Answer (score 0):

If `apt-get` is the package manager puppet is using, then you can try the following :

```
  # Create an array of package names that need to be installed
  $mypack = [ "linux-image-generic-lts-saucy", "linux-header-generic-lts-saucy", "lts-kernel-saucy" ]

  # Install all the packages
  package { $mypack :
              ensure => installed,
  }

  # Install other package that depends on the packages above :
  package { "lxc-docker" :
     ensure => installed,
     requires => Package[$mypack],
  }

  # Create an `exec` that will reboot the machine if a new package is installed
  # `refreshonly` sits there waiting for something new to happen
  exec { "reboot_machine" :
     command => "shutdown -r now",
     path => "/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin",
     subscribe => Package ["lxc-docker"],
     refreshonly => true,
  }
```